# How do I change opacity of entire row regardless of color?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a certain data-grid consisted of TextColumns and each of the cells differ in color. I am basing my color on certain data and because of this I have set the cell's background color appropriately. The issue that came from this is that now when I select a row, there is no way to see if it is selected. I dont want to dim each cell's color when I select the row, because I have a lot of columns. I just want to adjust the opacity of he selected row and not thing about the colors in individual cells. This is what I have tried:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.3"/>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

But I get the error: `Unexpected record in Baml stream. Trying to add to Setter which is not a collection or has a TypeConverter.` Is there a way to acheive my expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `Value` (note the `<Setter.Value>` element) property to a `SolidColorBrush`:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.3"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

You may also want to change the `TargetType` to `DataGridCell` for the background to be applied to the selected cells.

Comment: This did stop my app from crashing, but I am still not getting any transparency on selected row.

Comment: Did you change the TargetType as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make a difference. It does however mess up some other columns which I haven't colored, so I switched back to row

Comment: It works just fine for me. Please provide a repo of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ill post the update in a few mins, its a huge file and I have to get rid of all the bindings...

Comment: I think my problem is that I am setting the background property in two different styles. The first one which is targeting the cells of each column, and the second one being this one- the row

Comment: Well, that's another issue then.